# WLAN speed very slow (10 Mbps) when 850 Mbps in same location on other devices

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking, router, google-wifi

this is my first post - so I hope I'm asking correctly and in the right location with appropriate tags. I've done a ton of troubleshooting and can't crack this after probably 50 hours. I give up, please help me!

PC Set-up: Windows 10 Pro | Corei7-6700 CPU @ 3.40GHz

Wi-Fi:
TP-Link Archer T2UB Nano (USB wireless adapter) | Google Wifi

Download speed is 5-10 Mbps when I connect to the internet in my bedroom. I have new work laptop on the same desk. It gets 800+ Mbps speed in the same location. I also have a Google Mini on this desk, which receives 800+. I thought it may be a bad adapter, but then when I use my cell phone as a personal hotspot I will get good speed (for cellular) of nearly 200 Mbps. I've resorted to using my cell phone to write this post.

Troubleshooting I've tried so far:

- The signal strength is 90% in all instances. Sometimes, my cell phone has lower signal strength and still is 10x speed. (See Screenshots below, pls)
- Uninstalled / re-installed the wireless adapter
- Full network reset via Windows, multiple times
- Tried all different radio types (802.11a, 802.11ac, 802.11n, etc.)
- CMD / Powershell: FlushDNS, RegisterDNS, ipconfig /release & renew
- Wired connection - ran Ethernet directly to PC in the living room - got top speeds.
- Originally, my Wi-Fi didn't authenticate using WPA-3. Re-configured to run WPA-3 b/c I thought that might do it.
- Deleted my wireless profile using PowerShell and then re-installed that using Windows GUI
- Tried creating Guest wifi network to connect that way
- Tried 2.4GHz band and 5.0GHz band; as a test, the latter is all I'd accept going forward

I attached a screenshot regarding signal strength (I later flipped to WPA-3 Personal, but Signal Strength was unaffected). You'll see the comparison of my cell phone vs. wireless (Seinfeld fans may recognize the SSID). [signal strength strong!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgBeO.png)

**Please help me! I'm likely going to buy a new wireless adapter. It won't be the end of the world, but I spent so much time trying to fix it I'm having a hard time admitting defeat!**

**Update for the two questions (and thank you):**

I was able to find / identify the two bands. My adapter only lets me see & connect to the 2.4GHz (probably bc signal strength is much better). [see attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOCuZ.png)

@Spiff is right. I attached a like-for-like comparison. I believe the SSID broken into two bands (2.4 and 5.0), but I'm not sure. I always thought I was connecting to 5.0 GHz, but in getting this screenshot. It shows 2.4GHz which could be the issue. I can't select only 5.0 GHz band, but only to look for it first ([see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kh0o0.png)). I couldn't find a way to expand the RSSI you mentioned - maybe Google Wifi is limited? Also, thanks for the heads-up on 'signal strength is meaningless'. I had no idea; thought that was part of the speed loss, but agree it wouldn't explain a 95%+ loss in speed.

[Snapshot of services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y68iQ.png)

You've also asked me to specify my AP. I put in Google Wifi, but I realize that's not really clear. I'm using Google Wifi Model #GJ2CQ. Software version 14150.376.32, which I believe is their most recent.

@Rohit - I didn't follow you completely. What product are you referring to that you stay away from - Google Wifi or the TP-Link USB Nano adapter? I attached the latest speed test btw, to answer your other question. It's not usually this terrible (ha), but it's still 8-10 range on download. As reminder, on my laptop on same desk / same Wifi I'm getting 500-800 pending the time of day. [recent speed test, sad!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaF1W.png)

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to compare.  Please specify how each of the devices are connected.  My first impression is that there is some fine print somewhere that explains it. The first bit of creative blurb is that they have added the speed for 2.4GHz to  the speed on 5GHz to give you 600Mbps.  Are you sure that you are not getting 10Mbytes per second? Have you got both 2.5 and 5GHz Wifi? Will your router combine two bands? I have fallen for their ad on another adaptor, which turned out to have a high loss in speed.  I now keep away from their products.

Comment: Edit your question to include your AP (wireless router) make and model; this info is critical. Also, your screenshot comparison is a bad comparison because you weren't on 5GHz in the Vandelay case; please update that. If you're using the same SSID for both bands, consider splitting it (e.g. "Van-2.4GHz" vs "Van-5GHz") so you can guarantee your client is joining the 5GHz band. Signal strength percentages are meaningless. If you can find a way to see your RSSI (these are always given in negative dBm), that would be much better. Make sure your AP's 5GHz channel width is set to 80MHz or wider.

Comment: @Spiff I updated the post for all your comments. Please let me know what else I can do. Thank you very much.

Comment: @RohitGupta  I updated the post for all your comments. Please let me know what else I can do. Thank you very much!

Comment: I did some more reading on Google Wifi set-up. From Google: our Nest Wifi or Google Wifi network uses the same name for both the 2.4 and 5 GHz bands. All radio bands are active simultaneously. Based on the device capabilities and network conditions, Nest Wifi and Google Wifi attempt to select the band that will deliver the best performance for your device.

Comment: It's always recommended to have different SSIDs for the different frequency bands.

Comment: In answer to your question, I stay away from TPLink.  I suspect that if you buy a more upmarket product form them, it may do what you want.

Comment: @ChanganAuto thanks, yea Google Wifi unfortunately doesn't provide this option. I'd agree. I did find two separate BSSID. Is there a way thru Powershell or CMD to manually connect to BSSID? I tried setting up a manual connection, but it prompts for SSID (can't enter BSSID).

Answer (score 0):

Quick update & will close question - hopefully this helps someone in the same boat. I'm up to 150 MBPS speed after switching to a Wavlink PCI-e card.

The SSID still shows signal strength in the 60% range. I have a new wireless router coming too. Once installed, I should be able to get higher speeds. The big change was this adapter allowed me to specify (only 5.0 band) in the advanced settings in device manager, which carried the higher speed. At first, it connected by default to the stronger signal, slower 2.4 and that got 20-30 MPBS. With more customization, I was able to get onto higher band, and thus higher speeds. I expect 800+ once I get the stronger router and connection strength is in the 80%+ range.